# Runtime Tensorflow Placeholder Decision

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have 3 tensor flow placeholders and they are supposed to feed my Machine Learning model at runtime (Data can be sent in any placeholder, randomly). So I've written a generic code for x and model.

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, data_image_size ], name='input1')
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, data_image_size ], name='input2')
x3 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, data_image_size ], name='input3')
output = model.finalize(x, reuse=True)
```

Now during runtime, I generate a random number (among 1,2,3) and want to decide which placeholder to fit in **x**. Is there any way to do it?

Logically this makes sense to me,

```
def f1(): return x1  #(similarly for x2 and x3)

turn_1= tf.constant(1)
turn_2= tf.constant(2)
turn_3= tf.constant(3)

x = tf.case({tf.equal(turn, turn_1): f1, tf.equal(turn , turn_2): f2 ,
        tf.equal(turn, turn_3): f3 }, default=f1, exclusive=True)

output = model.finalize(x, reuse=True)

sess.run(output , dict_feed = {turn: 1 , x1 : X_input_data} )
sess.run(output , dict_feed = {turn: 3 , x3 : X_input_data} )
sess.run(output , dict_feed = {turn: 2 , x2 : X_input_data} )
```

But this gives me the error: **ValueError: Operation 'case_3/If_3/Merge' has been marked as not fetchable.**

Any suggestions if it's even possible to do it ? or should I hard code all the case with different variable names?

[Please NOTE: I need to share weights]

Comment: I need this arrangement for my project so can't change the random number generation part. Could have hard coded the solution as  ** output1 = model.finalize(x1, reuse=True) ; output2 = model.finalize(x2, reuse=True); output3 = model.finalize(x3, reuse=True); **